# Form a Json array in $.each function in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I need to create a array which needs to have custom index and value in jquery each function. For eg. i need to create an array like this [4: 'sampleIndex1','test':'sampleIndex2'];

But while using each function jquery takes '4' index will be an 4th index of an array remaining index 0,1,2,3 will set an value to empty. I dont need 0 1 2 3 index in the array. Instant help is much appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance,

Below are the sample code, 
I need to create div elements for select options.

```
<select name="question" id="myselect">
                            <option value="sample1">What is your father's name?</option>
                            <option value="sample2">What is your pets's name?</option>
                            <option value="sample3">What is your school's name?</option>
                        </select> 

$("#myselect").changeselect({width:400}); 
$.fn.changeselect=function(options){
    var defaults = {  
            width: 600 
    };      
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 
    var createhtml="";
var selectarr=new Array();
    $("option",this).each(function(k,v){
selectarr[$(this).attr('value')] = $(this).html();  
            createhtml +="<div id='"+k+"'>"+$(this).html()+"</div>";
    });
console.log(selectarr);
$(this).after(createhtml);

};
```

it shows [] empty array
Its need to be like this
[{"sample1":"What is your father's name?", "sample2":"What is your pets's name?", "sample3":"What is your school's name?"}]

Comment: Are you sure you don't need an object ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do and are you sure you want to create **JSON**? Please describe your problem better, provide your code, input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a javascript object.

```
(function () {

  var obj = new Object();

  $('#myselect option').each(function (index, option) {

    var option$ = $(option);

    $('<div/>').attr('id', option$.attr('value')).text(option$.html()).appendTo(/**/);

    obj[option$.attr('value')] = option$.html()

  });

  console.log(obj);

}).call(this)
```

Here is an example of sorts: http://jsbin.com/irohow/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid javascript array.  I think you want something more like:

```
[{4: 'sampleIndex1'}, {'test':'sampleIndex2'}]
```

Comment: yes... But what i need is to have different keys for this array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have string keys in an array - you should use an object for this -

```
var a = new Object();
a['4'] = "Some Value";
a['5'] = "Another Value";
```

This will give you -

```
{"4":"Some Value","5":"Another Value"}
```

Comment: And if you need to iterate over the keys, use something like [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#keys)